# Different forms of Kali Mata

Tags: markandeya-purana

I want to know the story of Rana Kali, a form of Kali Mata. And also the exact appearance of Rana Kali. We want to set up a temple of Rana Kali. Thus, we want to know how she would look like in the statue.
We would also like to know the surroundings of the statue.

Comment: Hello, welcome to Hinduism Stack Exchange. This question may fall into personal advice and there is a chance of getting closed. Please remove the personal advice part of the question.

Comment: Please read the banner on the right side regarding of this site personal advice.